# Logman issues with -v option

Tags: windows, perfmon, logman

I have a problem with logman.exe.

I can't get the -v option to work properly.

With this parameters:

**logman create counter EPVMON1 -f csv -v mmddoomm -max 100 -si 120 -o "F:/PerfLogs/EPVMON1" -cf "F:/EPVMON/EPVTASK/COUNTERS/disk.config"**

it creates correctly the entry in perfomance monitor but the information at the end of the filename are sequential number (nnnnnn) and not the date.

Using 'mmddhhmm' instead of 'mmddoomm'  I get an error that tell me to use  nnnnnnn or mmddoomm (I'm using Italian version of Windows XP), but in perfmon i can't find this mmddoomm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is for the english version but this [kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/827477) has a hot fix for logman that fixes a date related issue. Maybe you can download the hotfix and use the English version of logman. The only difference I can see is the use of mmddoomm or mmddhhmm as a -v option.

Comment: I already checked that kb article, but in the end I think I'll end using the english version as you have said (this also resolve lot of problem with customer with different locale settings).

Comment: I checked with an English version of the exe and it work fine! 
Thanks.